# How can I easily align an input with fluid attribute along with Icon in a grid.column?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I am trying to do something extremely basic, have a semantic-UI  control next to a simple Button/Icon to the right. I am working in a grid, and I want the fluid attribute on the  to fill up the space, but I want the icon/button to remain aligned.

No matter what i've tried, the button/icon always wraps to the next line. I have tried wrapping it in a  with no luck. The only way I have done it is to create another intermediate column and put the button/icon into that, but that has spacing issues to deal with.

This should be very easy, what am i missing?

```
        <Grid.Column width={7}>
                <Input icon label="Current User" fluid/>
                <Button icon basic><Icon name="user" /></Button>
       </Grid.Column>
```

[wrapping icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09u48.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

What about making it part of the input field?
According to the semantic ui docs you can do something like:

```
<Input label fluid>
  <Label>Current user</Label>
  <input />
  <Button icon>
    <Icon name="user" />
  </Button>
</Input>
```

See it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/l25qk539xl